# How to solve "IconData' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'"?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `SettingsTile` as below, it is no any problems,

```
SettingsSection(
  title: 'System',
  tiles: [
    SettingsTile(
      title: 'Reset',
      leading: Icon(Icons.clear_all_sharp),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()));
      },
    ),
```

But if I changed it to code as below:

```
SettingsSection(
  title: 'System',
  tiles: [
    _optionPush('Reset', Icons.clear_all_rounded, Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right), LoginPage, context),

Widget _optionPush(title, leading, trailing, func, context) {
  return SettingsTile(
    title: title,
    leading: leading,
    trailing: trailing,
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => func(),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

I got error `type 'IconData' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'`, what can I do next?

Comment: Are you missing a closing `]` for your `tiles:` parameter?

Comment: I found it, leading should be `leading: Icon(leading)`! you can answer me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to wrap the iconData with the `Icon()` widget

```
SettingsSection(
  title: 'System',
  tiles: [
    _optionPush('Reset', Icons.clear_all_rounded, Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right), LoginPage, context),

Widget _optionPush(title, leading, trailing, func, context) {
  return SettingsTile(
    title: title,
    leading: Icon(leading),
    trailing: Icon(trailing),
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => func(),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to wrap Icon() widget to icon data. Please see below.

```
SettingsSection(
  title: 'System',
  tiles: [
    _optionPush('Reset', Icon(Icons.clear_all_rounded, Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right), LoginPage, context),
```